# Typescript compilation error Generic type 'Type<t>' requires 1 type arguments after upgrading to angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have upgraded a visual studio project using angular 2x to angular 5x. But I'm now getting errors "Generic type 'Type' requires 1 type argument(s)" on typescript lines such as this that used to compile:

```
export declare const Yadda: Type[]:
```

Comment: Probably the definition of `Type` has changed, I think it represents a constructor signature, you could probably get away with `Type<any>[]`

Comment: The above comment seems to work, but since I have some other bugs I can't mark it as an answer yet. But hopefully this is the answer.

Comment: I later tracked down most of these errors to using the deprecated typings instead of specific @types